# How do you delete user data on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, users

I've managed to delete the accounts but there's still data left over. When I try to delete it I get the message "You require permission from S - 1 - 5 - 21 - 2782702860 - 1072350787 - 1006 to make changes to this folder." I'm the admin and it doesn't give me an option to provide permission. Is there any way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

This situation happens because you are not the owner of this folder of file, The default owner of a file or folder is the person who creates the resource.

Log on the computer with the account which created the folder of file, namely the owner, then you are permitted to modify the file or folder.

Also, you can follow this article to assign ownership of files and folders:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404240.aspx

Comment: I was the one who created the users (on the only administrator account). The others were deleted but apparently I do not have permissions to delete the data